# What counts as data/storage on iphone 4s?

Tags: storage

My phone has told me that my data/storage is hitting the limit. My question is what exactly makes up this data/storage? Is it the notes I keep on it? Saved texts?

I've seen the categories and how much room they take up including photos, audio/music, apps and data. Do I just need to go in and delete stuff to make more room?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to view the current storage being used, you can navigate to Settings > General > Storage & iCloud Usage > Manage Storage.    From here, you can see which apps are taking up a lot of space, how much space your photos / music are taking up, etc.

Once you know what's taking up all your space, you can delete things as needed.

Also, note that in older versions of iOS (depending on which you are currently on), space taken up by Messages was not shown here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused on what you mean by "data/storage", but here's what both of those terms mean:

Cellular data is anything that you do online when not connected to a Wi-Fi network---app downloads, video streaming (Hulu, Netflix, YouTube, etc.), browsing the web, anything you do over your cellular network.

Storage is anything actually stored on your iPhone---photos, apps, documents, music, movies, TV shows, text message conversations, etc.